# How can I prove this inequality for all a,b,c?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

> $\forall a, b, c \in F:$
>
> $0 \lt a \lt b \implies 2(b - a)a < b^{2} - a^{2} < 2(b - a)b$

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Note that $b^2 - a^2= (b-a)(b+a)$. Now divide everywhere by $b-a$.

Answer (score 0):

If we divide the whole inequality by $b-a > 0$, so we have to prove that 
$$2a < a+b < 2b$$
But $a < b$, so let's sum $a$ at both sides and then $2a < a+b$, at the same way let's sum $b$ at both sides and then $a+b < 2b$.